# Make sure steps run in sequence in Kettle?

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a Kettle transformation that inserts data in a number of database tables. For each table there is a separate transformation (with an injection step) that makes some calculations, checks the data and finally inserts. These sub-transformations are called using a `single threader` step.

The main transformation looks something like this:

```
Input from -----> Dummy -----> Dummy -----> Dummy -----> Done
   file             |            |            |
                    |            |            |
                    v            v            v
                  Select       Select       Select
                  values       values       values
                    |            |            |
                    |            |            |
                    v            v            v
                  Single       Single       Single
                threader 1   threader 2   threader 3
```

My problem is that I want to make sure that `Single threader 1` finishes for a specific row before `Single threader 2` runs for that row, and so on. This is because the first single threader adds a post in one table that then should be referenced in later tables and the database will throw an error if a reference to a post that does not exist (yet) is inserted.

I can't put the single threaders in one line because I need to discard all but a few fields of about 50 in total to match the injectors of the single threaders. That is what the `select values` does.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did u have a look on step "Block this step until steps finish" ?

Comment: @simar Yes, but I am not sure how to use it. If I understand it right, it blocks until *all* rows has passed through a step. That means that all my rows (10k+) needs to buffer somewhere, plus I cant take advantage of parallellism. I just want to block until *one* row has passed through a certain step.

Comment: Well if u don't need extensive data transform operation when I don't think it's a problem (or u can prepare all data before to start perform DDL). Batch insert in JDBC very effective. In my personal experience over million record was written into DB in less then 10s

Comment: @simar Ok, I will try that and see how the performance is. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example of such case

```
create table a (id serial primary key, md5 text not null);
create table b (id serial primary key, md5 text not null, a_id int not  null);
create table c (id serial primary key, md5 text not null, a_id int not null, b_id int not null);
```

And example of tranformation

[image]

I assume that data is flat so that each row at the beginning has data for all tables A, B and C.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is that injection steps of the single threader requires just a small subset of all the fields, so I have to remove some using the select values steps. If I put them all in a straight line, most of the field that is needed for single threader 3 will have already been removed before single threader 1.

Comment: In this example "select values" step in there to remove unnecessary field anymore, for example after i insert into table a i dont neeed a_md5 field, and i removed it,  but didn't fields b_md5 and c_md5, since they will be used in future steps.